# Pattern to support invoking both awaitable and non-awaitable delegate actions

Tags: c#, async-await, refactoring

I have a helper-method that wraps a callback invocation in some error handling, logging, status update logic, etc.

At the moment, I essentially have two copy-pastes of the same code, except one is async, and one is not.

Is there any way to continue supporting both async and sync callbacks, without so much code duplication?

```cs
private async Task SafeCallbackAsync(Func<Task> action, string context = null)
{
    try
    {
        // Comments, etc...
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        string initialStatus = $"{start:HH:mm:ss tt}: {context}...";
        SetAppStatus(initialStatus);
        
        // Invoke the callback
        await action.Invoke();

        // More Comments
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        SetAppStatus($"{end:HH:mm:ss tt}: Finished {context}. Time taken: {(end-start).TotalSeconds:0.00} seconds");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        HandleError(ex, $"Error while {context ?? "performing the requested action"}: ");
    }
}
```

```cs
private void SafeCallback(Action action, string context = null)
{
    try
    {
        // Comments, etc...
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        string initialStatus = $"{start:HH:mm:ss tt}: {context}...";
        SetAppStatus(initialStatus);
        
        // Invoke the callback
        action.Invoke();

        // More Comments
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        SetAppStatus($"{end:HH:mm:ss tt}: Finished {context}. Time taken: {(end-start).TotalSeconds:0.00} seconds");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        HandleError(ex, $"Error while {context ?? "performing the requested action"}: ");
    }
}
```

Reasons for wanting to avoid code duplication are the usual: Maintainability (I don't want someone to add a "feature" or make a fix in one place but forget to change the other), seeing 99% copy-pasted code hurts my soul, etc...

The following compiles, but seems ill-advised and with potentially damaging side-effects (e.g. running the action on a new thread):

```cs
private void SafeCallback(Action action, string context = null) =>
    SafeCallback(() => Task.Run(action), context).Wait();
```

Not to mention the overhead of converting a sync action to async, then back to sync again.

Comment: There are lots of options, but the best is to not do that at all. Either your library provides operations that are inherently asynchronous or which are not. Support whatever is inherently part of the API and require client code to deal with the rest. It's hard enough to decide how to wrap async in sync or vice a versa when you actually know what the top-level code is doing. A library should never be doing this. See duplicate.

Comment: In our case, this is a UI application. Some control even-handlers contain only UI actions (in which case they should by synchronous callbacks) while other event-handlers kick off network or disk IO actions, in which case they should by `async void` event-handlers. I imagine any UI will similarily have a mix of async and non-async callbacks, so it's not as simple as only supporting one or the other.

Comment: The same basic philosophy still applies. Within your program, there are different components that should be loosely- or completely un-coupled. Each component is the equivalent of a library API. There are things that are inherently async and other things which are not. You should almost never have a situation where you, in the same program, do the same thing in two different ways.

Comment: That said, I have experienced situations where a generalized layer needs to support both sync and async operations and that requires a bit of finagling to get right. If you have something similar, you should ask a different question, i.e. not so generalized and instead provide a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the _specific_ scenario, explain what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.